# Can gdb make a function pointer point to another location?

Tags: c, macos, gdb

I'll explain:

Let's say I'm interested in replacing the `rand()` function used by a certain application.

So I attach gdb to this process and make it load my custom shared library (which has a customized `rand()` function):

```
call (int) dlopen("path_to_library/asdf.so")
```

This would place the customized `rand()` function inside the process' memory. However, at this point the symbol *rand* will still point to the default `rand()` function. Is there a way to make gdb point the symbol to the new `rand()` function, forcing the process to use my version?

I must say I'm also not allowed to use the `LD_PRELOAD` (linux) nor `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` (mac os x) methods for this, because they allow code injection only in the beginning of the program execution.

The application that I would like to replace `rand()`, starts several threads and some of them start new processes, and I'm interested in injecting code on one of these new processes. As I mentioned above, GDB is great for this purpose because it allows code injection into a specific process.

Comment: Are the subprocesses of interest just forked copies of the original, or do they also `exec()` new images?

Comment: @llasram they are not forked copies.

Comment: Another question -- do you have any `gdb` version constraints, or could you install and use an arbitrarily recent version?

Comment: There are no gdb version constraints.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I followed [this post](http://timetobleed.com/dynamic-linking-elf-vs-mach-o/) and [this presentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/35191054/Function-hooking-for-OSX-and-Linux) and came up with the following set of gdb commands for OSX with x86-64 executable, which can be loaded with `-x` option when attaching to the process:

```
set $s = dyld_stub_rand
set $p = ($s+6+*(int*)($s+2))
call (void*)dlsym((void*)dlopen("myrand.dylib"), "my_rand")
set *(void**)$p = my_rand
c
```

The magic is in `set $p = ...` command. `dyld_stub_rand` is a 6-byte jump instruction. Jump offset is at `dyld_stub_rand+2` (4 bytes). This is a `$rip`-relative jump, so add offset to what `$rip` would be at this point (right after the instruction, `dyld_stub_rand+6`).

This points to a symbol table entry, which should be either real `rand` or dynamic linker routine to load it (if it was never called). It is then replaced by `my_rand`.

Sometimes gdb will pick up `dyld_stub_rand` from libSystem or another shared library, if that happens, unload them first with `remove-symbol-file` before running other commands.

Answer (score 10):

This question intrigued me, so I did a little research.  What you are looking for is a '[dll injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection)'.  You write a function to replace some library function, put it in a .so, and tell ld to preload your dll.  I just tried it out and it worked great!  I realize this doesn't really answer your question in relation to gdb, but I think it offers a viable workaround.

For a gdb-only solution, see my [other solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270281/can-gdb-make-a-function-pointer-point-to-another-location/3274185#3274185)

---

```
// -*- compile-command: "gcc -Wall -ggdb -o test test.c"; -*-
// test.c

#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //should print a fairly random number...
    printf("Super random number: %d\n", rand());

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/ -*- compile-command: "gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared my_rand.c -o my_rand.so"; -*-
//my_rand.c

int rand(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

---

compile both files, then run:
`LD_PRELOAD="./my_rand.so" ./test`

`Super random number: 42`

Comment: I should have added that I could not use LD_PRELOAD (linux) nor DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES (mac os x) to achieve this. The reason for this is that the program I'm trying to "hack" starts a dozen of threads that later loads a bunch of other processes, and my interest is one of these processes. 

So, the LD_PRELOAD method does not allow me to inject code in the process I'm actually interested, it only allows code to be injected in the process created by the initial execution of the program.

That's why my question is specific for GDB, it allows me to attach my code on the right process!

Comment: @karlphillip That does thicken the plot considerably!

Comment: Why not just `export LD_PRELOAD="./my_rand.so"; test`?

Comment: As stated in the question, please keep answers restricted to the Mac OS X environment.

Answer (score 5):

I have a new solution, based on the <del>new</del> original constraints.  (I am not deleting my first answer, as others may find it useful.)

I have been doing a bunch of research, and I think it would work with a bit more fiddling.

1. In your .so rename your replacement rand function, e.g my_rand
2. Compile everything and load up gdb
3. Use `info functions` to find the address of `rand` in the symbol table
4. Use dlopen then dlsym to load the function into memory and get its address

   `call (int) dlopen("my_rand.so", 1)` -> -val-

   `call (unsigned int) dlsym(-val-, "my_rand")` -> my_rand_addr
5. -the tricky part- Find the hex code of a `jumpq 0x*my_rand_addr*` instruction
6. Use `set {int}*rand_addr* = *my_rand_addr*` to change symbol table instruction
7. `Continue` execution: now whenever `rand` is called, it will jump to `my_rand` instead

This is a bit complicated, and very round-about, but I'm pretty sure it would work.  The only thing I haven't accomplished yet is creating the `jumpq` instruction code.  Everything up until that point works fine.

Comment: The problem with step 5 is that you won't be able to find any jumps to *my_rand_addr* since this code was just loaded and is not used by the application. 

But I tested the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270281/can-gdb-make-a-function-pointer-point-to-another-location/3276887#3276887 and it worked.

Comment: @karlphillip You don't need to find the jump instruction in the code, you make it yourself. The format of the `jumpq` instruction is well specified, you just look it up and the find out what the hex value is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do this in a running program, but perhaps `LD_PRELOAD` will work for you.  If you set this environment variable to a list of shared objects, the runtime loader will load the shared object early in the process and allow the functions in it to take precedence over others.

```
LD_PRELOAD=path_to_library/asdf.so path/to/prog
```

You do have to do this before you start the process but you don't have to rebuild the program.

Answer (score 2):

Several of the answers here and the [code injection article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/code_injection.aspx) you linked to in your answer cover chunks of what I consider the optimal `gdb`-oriented solution, but none of them pull it all together or cover all the points.  The code-expression of the solution is a bit long, so here's a summary of the important steps:

1. **Load the code to inject**. Most of the answers posted here use what I consider the best approach -- call `dlopen()` in the inferior process to link in a shared library containing the injected code.  In the article you linked to the author instead loaded a *relocatable* object file and hand-linked it against the inferior.  This is quite frankly insane -- relocatable objects are not "ready-to-run" and include relocations even for internal references.  And hand-linking is tedious and error-prone -- far simpler to let the real runtime dynamic linker do the work.  This does mean getting `libdl` into the process in the first place, but there are many options for doing that.
2. **Create a detour**. Most of the answers posted here so far have involved locating the PLT entry for the function of interest, using that to find the matching GOT entry, then modifying the GOT entry to point to your injected function.  This is fine up to a point, but certain linker features -- e.g., use of `dlsym` -- can circumvent the GOT and provide direct access to the function of interest.  The only way to be certain of intercepting all calls to a particular function is overwrite the initial instructions of that function's code in-memory to create a "detour" redirecting execution to your injected function.
3. **Create a trampoline** (optional).  Frequently when doing this sort of injection you'll want to call the original function whose invocation you are intercepting.  The way to allow this with a function detour is to create a small code "trampoline" which includes the overwritten instructions of the original function then a jump to the remainder of the original.  This can be complex, because any IP-relative instructions in the copied set need to be modified to account for their new addresses.
4. **Automate it all**.  These steps can be tedious, even if doing some of the simpler solutions posted in other answers.  The best way to ensure that the steps are done correctly every time with variable parameters (injecting different functions, etc) is to automate their execution.  Starting with the 7.0 series, `gdb` has included the ability to write new commands in Python.  This support can be used to implement a turn-key solution for injecting and detouring code in/to the inferior process.

Here's an example.  I have the same `a` and `b` executables as before and an `inject2.so` created from the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int (*rand__)(void) = NULL;

int
rand(void)
{
    int result = rand__();
    printf("rand invoked! result = %d\n", result);
    return result % 47;
}
```

I can then place my Python `detour` command in `detour.py` and have the following `gdb` session:

```
(gdb) source detour.py
(gdb) exec-file a
(gdb) set follow-fork-mode child
(gdb) catch exec
Catchpoint 1 (exec)
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/llasram/ws/detour/a 
a: 1933263113
a: 831502921
[New process 8500]
b: 918844931
process 8500 is executing new program: /home/llasram/ws/detour/b
[Switching to process 8500]

Catchpoint 1 (exec'd /home/llasram/ws/detour/b), 0x00007ffff7ddfaf0 in _start ()
   from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4005d0: file b.c, line 7.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdd68) at b.c:7
7       {
(gdb) detour libc.so.6:rand inject2.so:rand inject2.so:rand__
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
rand invoked! result = 392103444
b: 22

Program exited normally.
```

In the child process, I create a detour from the `rand()` function in `libc.so.6` to the `rand()` function in `inject2.so` and store a pointer to a trampoline for the original `rand()` in the `rand__` variable of `inject2.so`.  And as expected, the injected code calls the original, displays the full result, and returns that result modulo 47.

Due to length, I'm just linking to a pastie containing [the code for my `detour` command](http://pastie.org/1163586).  This is a fairly superficial implementation (especially in terms of the trampoline generation), but it should work well in a large percentage of cases.  I've tested it with `gdb` 7.2 (most recently released version) on Linux with both 32-bit and 64-bit executables.  I haven't tested it on OS X, but any differences should be relatively minor.

Answer (score 1):

For executables you can easily find the address where the function pointer is stored by using objdump. For example:

```
objdump -R /bin/bash | grep write
00000000006db558 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  fwrite
00000000006db5a0 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  write
```

Therefore, 0x6db5a0 is the adress of the pointer for `write`. If you change it, calls to write will be redirected to your chosen function. Loading new libraries in gdb and getting function pointers has been covered in earlier posts. The executable and every library have their own pointers. Replacing affects only the module whose pointer was changed.

For libraries, you need to find the base address of the library and add it to the address given by objdump. In Linux, `/proc/<pid>/maps` gives it out. I don't know whether position-independent executables with address randomization would work. `maps`-information might be unavailable in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the function you want to replace is in a shared library, you can redirect calls to that function at runtime (during debugging) by poking at the PLT. Here is an article that might be helpful:

[Shared library call redirection using ELF PLT infection](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=56&id=7)

It's written from the standpoint of malware modifying a program, but a much easier procedure is adaptable to live use in the debugger. Basically you just need to find the function's entry in the PLT and overwrite the address with the address of the function you want to replace it with.

Googling for "PLT" along with terms like "ELF", "shared library", "dynamic linking", "PIC", etc. might find you more details on the subject.

Comment: Does OSX use some strange form of dynamic linking? Almost everyone else uses ELF...

Comment: Yeah, due its Mach and NeXTSTEP heritage, OS X uses Mach-O.

Answer (score 1):

You can still us `LD_PRELOAD` if you make the preloaded function understand the situations it's getting used in.  Here is an example that will use the `rand()` as normal, except inside a forked process when it will always return 42.  I use the dl routines to load the standard library's `rand()` function into a function pointer for use by the hijacked `rand()`.

```
// -*- compile-command: "gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared my_rand.c -o my_rand.so -ldl"; -*-
//my_rand.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <dlfcn.h>


int pid = 0;
int (*real_rand)(void) = NULL;

void f(void) __attribute__ ((constructor));

void f(void) {
    pid = getpid();
    void* dl = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(dl) {
        real_rand = dlsym(dl, "rand");
    }
}

int rand(void) 
{
    if(pid == getpid() && real_rand)
        return real_rand();
    else
        return 42;
}
```

---

```
//test.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    printf("Super random number: %d\n", rand());
    if(fork()) {
        printf("original process rand: %d\n", rand());

    } else {
        printf("forked process rand: %d\n", rand());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
jdizzle@pudding:~$ ./test
Super random number: 1804289383
original process rand: 846930886
forked process rand: 846930886

jdizzle@pudding:~$ LD_PRELOAD="/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./my_rand.so" ./test
Super random number: 1804289383
original process rand: 846930886
forked process rand: 42
```

Comment: Did you notice that I already had an answer describing the same technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270281/can-gdb-make-a-function-pointer-point-to-another-location/3708318#3708318 ?

Comment: Your example both won't compile as posted and doesn't work.  Mine is also simpler.

Comment: Those are reasons to improve my answer or propose improvements, not create an entirely different answer and down-vote mine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial incredibly useful, and so far its the only way I managed to achieve what I was looking with GDB: **Code Injection into Running Linux Application**: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/code_injection.aspx

There is also a good **Q&A on code injection for Mac** here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-30-code-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use code injection as a method of mocking for automated testing of C code.  If that's the sort of situation you're in -- if your use of GDB is simply because you're not interested in the parent processes, and not because you want to interactively select the processes which are of interest -- then you can still use `LD_PRELOAD` to achieve your solution.  Your injected code just needs to determine whether it is in the parent or child processes.  There are several ways you could do this, but on Linux, since your child processes `exec()`, the simplest is probably to look at the active executable image.

I produced two executables, one named `a` and the other `b`.  Executable `a` prints the result of calling `rand()` twice, then `fork()`s and `exec()`s `b` twice.  Executable `b` print the result of calling `rand()` once.  I use `LD_PRELOAD` to inject the result of compiling the following code into the executables:

```
// -*- compile-command: "gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -Wall -std=gnu99 -O2 -pipe -fPIC -shared -o inject.so inject.c"; -*-
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define constructor __attribute__((__constructor__))

typedef int (*rand_t)(void);

typedef enum {
    UNKNOWN,
    PARENT,
    CHILD
} state_t;

state_t state = UNKNOWN;
rand_t rand__ = NULL;

state_t
determine_state(void)
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    char linkpath[PATH_MAX] = { 0, };
    char exepath[PATH_MAX] = { 0, };
    ssize_t exesz = 0;

    snprintf(linkpath, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%d/exe", pid);
    exesz = readlink(linkpath, exepath, PATH_MAX);
    if (exesz < 0)
        return UNKNOWN;

    switch (exepath[exesz - 1]) {
    case 'a':
        return PARENT;
    case 'b':
        return CHILD;
    }

    return UNKNOWN;
}

int
rand(void)
{
    if (state == CHILD)
        return 47;
    return rand__();
}

constructor static void
inject_init(void) 
{
    rand__ = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "rand");
    state = determine_state();
}
```

The result of running `a` with and without injection:

```
$ ./a
a: 644034683
a: 2011954203
b: 375870504
b: 1222326746
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/inject.so ./a
a: 1023059566
a: 986551064
b: 47
b: 47
```

I'll post a gdb-oriented solution later.

Comment: Thank you! But as I previously stated on the question, I'm not allowed to use LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: @karlphillip Oh! I thought you just didn't think `LD_PRELOAD` could provide the effect you were trying to achieve, or at least that's how I read your `LD_PRELOAD`-related comments.  I'll post a (IMHO) clean `gdb`-based solution soon.

Comment: You need to #define __USE_GNU before including dlfcn.h if you want to use RTLD_NEXT (at least in my version of dlfcn.h).  Also, determine_state() is not run at fork() time, so the state will never change.

Comment: @llasram don't be such a whiner next time.